# importing jquery in ES6

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

In the same jsx file I have the next declarations:

```
import {jQuery} from '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

however I get the error:

```
someModuleBundle.js:94625 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

any ideas why?

I am using webpack

Comment: Probably Bootstrap requires a *global* jQuery variable. What kind of bundler are you using?

Comment: What bundler do you use (rollup, webpack, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to shim jquery so its available globally. Try this.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

Link for the same
https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx